# Travel from Europe to Latin-America by boat in November

Tags: sailing, atlantic-ocean

I am planning a trip to Chile and live in The Netherlands. I would love to cross the ocean by boat instead of flying there. I already checked the option to go by cargo boat, but it is quite expensive. I also browsed sites for private boats who need crew, but it seems impossible to find out where they want to go and when. I do have sailing experience, but not on the sea. I am sure that I can be useful on board. I do not mind arriving at another part of Latin-America. I can travel on land to Chile. Does anybody have tips to make my dreamtrip become reality? Crossing the ocean by boat from Europe to Latin-America that is. Is november a possible timing for crossing by sea anyway? If October or December are better months, I do not mind at all.

Comment: Likely not suitable (due to time of commitment) but it does show when they sailed which direction: http://fairtransport.eu/sail-along/ A Den Helder based (if elsewhere registered) company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crossing the Atlantic by sailing boat, South America to Europe](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26737/crossing-the-atlantic-by-sailing-boat-south-america-to-europe)

Comment: The possible duplicate is about travel from South America to Europe, so the other way round and does not have a good answer for this question, so I vote leave open.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of sites where captains and passengers can make a match for a given boat trip:

- [Find a crew](https://www.findacrew.net/): recreational, professional, commercial
- [Desperate sailors](http://www.desperatesailors.com/)
- [7Knots](http://www.7knots.com/)
- [The float plan](http://floatplan.com/): *you can find new crew members, find boats to sail on and ask fellow sailors for advice and tips*.
- [Latitude 38](http://www.latitude38.com/)
- [Crewseekers](http://www.crewseekers.net/): *We have a wide variety of exciting yacht crew opportunities available worldwide, from daysailing to transocean – for all experience levels*.

Since November is almost over I cannot tell if you'd have found anything relevant here. However, a quick browse over these sites revealed quite a lot of opportunities.