# Ferries from Europe to Kingston, Jamaica or Port of Spain, Trinidad & Tobago

Tags: europe, ferries, sea-travel, caribbean

Is there any way to travel to either Jamaica or Trinidad by ferry from anywhere in Europe?

I only need it one-way. I would rather avoid long-haul flights.

Comment: NB If it crosses the Atlantic Ocean, it wouldn't be called a ferry; *ocean liners* and some *cruise ships* are what you want, or perhaps a freighter that can take passengers. See for instance *[How can I cross the Atlantic by ship from Europe to New York?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13437/)* or *[Are there any vessels from French Guiana to Europe?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22863)*, and posts under the tags [sea-travel] and [freighter-travel].

Comment: Have you not thought about a one way cruise ship? Several operate from North West Europe to the Caribbean. Royal Caribbean may be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably out of luck without delving into the world of freighter travel or private boats.

There are cruises from Europe to the Caribbean.  However none that I could find go via Jamaica or Trinidad and Tobago.  [Royal Caribbean](http://www.royalcaribbean.com.au/findacruise/destinations/home.do?dest=T.ATL&wuc=AUS), for instance, only runs them via [Puerto Rico](http://cruiseandvacationexperts.com/cruise-ships/royal-caribbean-specials/).  [Compilation](http://www.travelweekly.com/Cruise/Trans-Oceanic-World/Transatlantic) [sites](http://www.cleancruising.com.au/region.asp?region=21) also don't list those two as possible stops either.

Assuming you get to the Caribbean, [travelling on to those two by boat are still limited](http://www.travellerspoint.com/guide/Caribbean_ferries/):

> Because of the fact that Jamaica is not really close to most other Caribbean islands, international services are non-existent.

Similarly, nothing actually running is listed for Trinidad and Tobago (the one ferry line mentioned has last updated their website in 2011 mentioning they are "looking forward to the launching date to be executed").